# Append rm to a find statement

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I Have the following script to HandBrake a folder

```
find "$TRANSCODEDIR"/* -type f -exec bash -c 'HandBrakeCLI -i "$1" -o "${1%\.*}".mp4 --preset="$PRESET"' __ {} \;
```

I want to be append to the end of this line a rm (remove) command so when Hanbrake is done with the file to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass more than one -exec switch to find, how about:

```
find "$TRANSCODEDIR"/* -type f -exec bash -c 'HandBrakeCLI -i "$1" -o "${1%.*}".mp4 --preset="$PRESET"' __ {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Are you sure you can trust that to no `rm` the file too early? Removing it after it's opened shouldn't be a problem (I'm not familiar with HandBrake, though), but there may be a chance it could get removed before it's opened.

Comment: @Dennis: Those `-exec` options are anded together, meaning the second `-exec` only happens if the first returns true (0).

Answer (score 1):

```
find .... -exec bash -c 'HandBrake .... --preset="$PRESET"; rm "$1"' __ {} \;
```

Comment: You might want to do `HandBrake ... && rm ...` (although I don't know if that might be needed here).

Comment: +1 Prefer this to multiple `-exec` options as you are starting a shell anyway.